# Setting labels and color to a new layer in a QGIS processing script

Tags: qgis-processing, style, post-processing

I have created a new layer by an algorithm (intersection; buffer and so on) in a processing script. I would like to add a label to the new layer through a field (id number) of the attributes table.  And customize the color and transparency. Can I automate this? I found the def postProcessAlgorithm for this and think this is what I need to run afterwards. But I am not quite clear how to use it and how to access the attributes table content. Or should I not set this individually and instead regulate it using a type of layer template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution that works for me. I load a style file at the end of the process.

```
  def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, model_feedback):
        # Use a multi-step feedback, so that individual child algorithm progress reports are adjusted for the
        # overall progress through the model
        feedback = QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback(1, model_feedback)
        results = {}
        outputs = {}

   
        alg_params = {
            'INPUT': parameters['EingabeFlurstcke'],
            'INPUT_FIELDS': [''],
            'OVERLAY': parameters['EingabeEnergiet'],
            'OVERLAY_FIELDS': [''],
            'OVERLAY_FIELDS_PREFIX': '',
            'OUTPUT': parameters['Flurstuecke_energie']
        }
        outputs['Overlap'] = processing.run('native:intersection', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
        results['Flurstuecke_Energielandschaft'] = outputs['Overlap']['OUTPUT']
        
        feedback.setCurrentStep(1)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Set a Style
        alg_params = {
            'INPUT': outputs['Overlap']['OUTPUT'],
            'STYLE': 'C:\\Users\\User\\.....qml'
        }
        outputs['SetzeStilFrVektorlayer'] = processing.run('qgis:setstyleforvectorlayer', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
        return results
```